# Add item to ListAPIView

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have ordinary ListAPIView with specified model and serializer classes. I need to add one additional item to the end of list. This item should be created manually (no queryset) and should have the same structure as other items.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can override `list` method for this:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response

class YoourView(generics.ListAPIView):

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = UserSerializer(queryset, many=True)

        # append serializer's data with some additional value
        response_list = serializer.data 
        response_list.append(some_value)
        return Response(response_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework.response import Response


class MyListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = MySerializer
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response_list = list(super().list(request, *args, **kwargs))
        custom_dict = {
            "key_1": "value 1",
            "key_2": "value 2"
        }
        response_list.append(custom_dict)
        return Response(data=response_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better that you keep the `get_queryset`, `filter_queryset` and `get_serializer` function in case you would modify the `serializer_class` instead of using the default `serializer_class`.

```
class YourView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = DefaultQueryset
    serializer_class = DefaultSerializer

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        response_list = serializer.data 
        response_list.append(some_value)
        return Response(response_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you to keep your actual load separated from the extra data you're trying to pass. This will help you avoid a lot of conflicts when you'll iterate over those later on.

Try this:

```
class YourView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = YourModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = YourSerializer

def list(self, request, args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(self.get_queryset(), many=True)
    load = serializer.data
    newdict = {'your_new_data': 666}
    response_list = {'load': load, 'extra': newdict}
    return Response(response_list)
```